# Without appealing to choice, can we prove that if $X$ is well-orderable, then so too is $2^X$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice, well-orders

Without appealing to the axiom of choice, it can be shown that (Proposition:) if $X$ is well-orderable, then $2^X$ is **totally**-orderable.

**Question:** can we show the stronger result that if $X$ is well-orderable, then so too is $2^X$?

*Proof of Proposition*. Pick any well-ordering of $X$. Then the lexicographic order totally orders $2^X$.

More explicitly: for any two $f,g \in 2^X$, define $f < g$ iff

1. there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$, and
2. if $x \in X$ is minimal such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$, then $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$.

It can be shown that $<$ totally-orders $2^X$.

Comment: See also: [Totally ordering the power set of a well ordered set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/90078).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

The axiom "If $X$ can be well-ordered then $2^X$ can be well-ordered" implies the axiom of choice in $\sf ZF$. In $\sf ZFA$ or $\sf ZF-Reg$ this is no longer true, though.

To see more details see the first part of Jech, *The Axiom of Choice* Chapter 9.

One *very* interesting observation about the fact that in $\sf ZFA$ this statement does not prove the axiom of choice, is that if $\psi(X)$ is a statement in which all the quantifiers are either bounded in $y$ or bounded in $\mathcal P(y)$ (where $y$ is a variable, of course), and in $\sf ZF$ we have that $\forall X\psi(X)$ implies $\sf AC$, then in $\sf ZFA$ we have that $\forall X\psi(X)$ implies that the power set of a well-ordered set is well-orderable. (This is the first problem in the aforementioned chapter 9.)

Comment: Or see Theorem 9 [here](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/502-equivalents-of-the-axiom-of-choice/#more-2422). And one can go further: One cannot even prove in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that if $X$ is well-orderable, then $2^{2^X}$ is linearly orderable.

Comment: @user18921: I am not a big fond of political comments. $\sf ZFA$ is $\sf ZF$ with atoms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, ahh sorry man; I was just trying to be funny. If you had let me know immediately, I would have just deleted it.

Comment: @user18921: It's fine. Nothing that a few bottles of 20+ years old single malt won't cure... ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, ha ha fair enough. Sorry though. Btw, if you know of any good articles about ZFA, please link. I'm not even sure what the axioms would be - obviously we weaken extensionality, but what else needs modifying?

Comment: @user18921: There is a good covering in Jech's book (the one quoted in the post, as well Set Theory, ch. 15 somewhere). Mostly we say that every element is a set or an atom, the sets satisfy $\sf ZF(C)$, and we usually require that the class of atoms is a non-empty set (but sometimes it can be a proper class, too).

Comment: Makes sense. Yeah I have heard nothing but good things about Jech's book, will probably order it next chance I get. Btw, it seems completely surprising to me that allowing atoms can have such a dramatic effect on the theory. Is that because ZFA cannot prove that every set is equinumerous to a pure set?

Comment: @user18921: Yes. Given a model of $\sf ZFA$ (with infinitely many atoms) we can create an inner model including all the pure sets and all the atoms, so all the pure sets are well-orderable, but the set of atoms need not be well-orderable. It is trivial to see that the power set of a well-ordered set is well-orderable (because well-ordered sets are equipotent to pure sets, whose power sets are pure sets so equipotent with ordinals again). On the other hand, the atoms may give us a counterexample.

Comment: I see. Is this why you were saying the other day that atoms immensely complicate forcing, or were you referring to a different problem?

Comment: @user18921: Atoms make it much easier to construct models without the axiom of choice, but the pure sets in those models are still well-orderable. We can violate that as well using forcing, but then it becomes more complicated because you need to handle the atoms as well (it's not *very* hard, but it does require more work). But if you want to violate the axiom of choice with forcing, you may as well do it in $\sf ZF$ rather than $\sf ZFA$.

Comment: Thank you. I have about a million more questions about atoms, but I should probably get my hands on Jech's book first. Enjoy your whiskey.

Comment: @user18921: The small book goes for like 15 USD as a Dover reprint. One of the best buys in my life. As for the drinking, (1) I don't have any whiskey, because I have a Scottish whisky; and (2) I was hinting that you should compensate my "mental anguish" by buying me *more* whisky! ;-)

Comment: (1) [This](http://www.amazon.com/Set-Theory-Kenneth-Kunen/dp/1848900503/ref=pd_bxgy_b_text_z) small book? It appears to be 400 pages long... (2) if you can still notice these sorts of small details, then you haven't had enough whisky (3) next time you're in Melbourne, Australia, remind me.

Comment: @user18921: (1)You are confusing Kunen and Jech. I'm talking about [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=1qEgAQAAMAAJ&hl=en). (2) Those are important details, not small details. People have been lynched/severely beaten for less. (3) I'll hold you for it, someday.

Comment: (1) According to von Neumann, we should have started at zero. (0) This sentence is empty of information. (2) I thought you were referring to a chapter in [this](http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/3540440852) book by Jech, rather than a whole book unto itself. (3) Looking forward to it.

Comment: @user18921: According to Peano, at one. (2) If you want to buy the big book, go ahead. It's a great book, and I have referred to Chapter 15 in *that* one; but you can also find a similar treatment in the small book which concentrates on $\sf AC$. (3) Count to $\omega_5$, and I'll be there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, awesome, I'll get my money ready ;)

Comment: I don't understand why ZFA doesn't prove that if the power set of every well-orderable set is well-orderable, the axiom of choice is true. Shouldn't ZFA be equivalent to ZF because in ZFA, the axiom of regularity proves that no urelements exist? Maybe its formal system would be different but equivalent to the formal system of ZF.

Comment: @Timothy: Do you understand why ZF proves that there is exactly one object without elements, whereas ZFA doesn't?

Comment: @Timothy: Or, do you understand why ZF does not prove that every set can be well-ordered, but ZFC does?

Comment: Yes, I understand why ZF proves that there is exactly one object without elements and can't prove choice. I don't know how to write a formal proof in ZF but have some intuition about what can be proven in ZF. I think that in ZFA, the axiom of regularity is a different statement than the one I would have thought was called the axiom of regularity from which it follows that there are no urelements.

Comment: @Timothy: Then you should be able to understand how ZFA doesn't prove that "sets of ordinals+AC" decide the universe, whereas ZF does.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't know how to prove in ZF that every set has an ordinal rank because I don't know what the axiom of regularity states. I think that in ZF, the axiom of regularity is equivalent to the statement that if you invent a function that assigns the empty set to 0, to every limit ordinal the union of what it assigns to smaller ordinals and to every nonzero nonlimit ordinal, the power set of what it assigns to the previous ordinal, every set belongs to an image of that function. I don't know what the axiom of regularity states in ZFA.

Comment: I don't see how to deduce the axiom of choice from the statement that the power set of every well-orderable set is well-orderable. I know how to show that each set that can be gotten by applying the power set operation to the set of all natural numbers a finite number of times can be well ordered but how can I show that there's a uniform way of deciding for each of those sets one such well-ordering of it?

Comment: @Timothy: Have you looked down to see the explicit proof given by Camilo? Note that this requires quite heavy use of transfinite recursion and the axiom of regularity.

Answer (score 14):

Asaf states in his answer that if for all well-orderable sets $X$ the power set $\mathcal P(X)$ is also well-orderable, then the axiom of choice must hold. There is a proof of this left as exercise in Kunen's *Set Theory*, 2011 ed., exercise I.12.17, which comes with a hint, and is done as follows:

In $\mathsf{ZF}$, including the axiom of regularity of course, suppose that for any cardinal $\aleph$, $2^{\aleph}$ is well-orderable, then this implies that for any ordinal $\delta$, $\mathcal P(\delta)$ is well-orderable; as in $\mathsf{ZF}$ ,$\delta\thickapprox \aleph$, where $\aleph$ is the greatest cardinal with $\aleph\leq \delta.$

Let us prove by transfinite induction on $\gamma$ that $R(\gamma)$, the class of all sets of rank $\gamma$; which is a set, is well-orderable for all ordinals $\gamma$. As we are assuming $V=WF$ this will imply $\mathsf {AC}$.

Suppose $\gamma\neq 0 $ is such that the property holds for all $\alpha<\gamma$. If $\gamma=\alpha+1$ is successor, then as $R(\alpha)$ is well-orderable there is some ordinal $\delta$ such that $\delta\thickapprox R(\alpha)$, hence $R(\gamma)=\mathcal P(R(\gamma))\thickapprox \mathcal P(\delta)$, but as $\mathcal P(\delta)$ is well-orderable by hypothesis, $R(\gamma)$ is then well-orderable.

Now suppose $\gamma$ is limit. By Hartogs' Theorem; in $\mathsf{ZF}$, there is some cardinal $\kappa$ with  $\kappa \npreceq R(\gamma)$. Fix a well-order $\sqsubset$ of $P(\kappa)$. Let us define by induction on $\alpha<\gamma$ an explicit well-order $\lhd_{\alpha}$ on $R(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha<\gamma$. Furthermore, let us construct each $\lhd_{\alpha}$ in such a manner that for any $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$ we have $\lhd_{\beta}\cap (R(\alpha)\times R(\alpha))\subseteq \lhd_{\alpha}$.

Let $\lhd_0$ be the canonical well-order of $R(0)$. Suppose we have defined $\lhd_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha<\beta$ for some $\beta\leq \gamma$, meeting the conditions above. There are two cases:

Case $\beta=\alpha+1$. Since $\kappa\npreceq R(\alpha)$, we must have that $\bf{type}$$(R(\alpha),\lhd_{\alpha})<\kappa.$ Let $f_{\alpha}:(R(\alpha),\lhd_{\alpha})\rightarrow \kappa$ be the canonical embedding, the one that maps $(R(\alpha),\lhd_{\alpha})$ into an initial segment of $\kappa$. Then $f_{\alpha}[R(\alpha)]=\mu$ for some $\mu<\kappa$, so that $f^{-1}_{\alpha}[ \ ]:P(\mu)\rightarrow P(R(\alpha))$ is a bijection, but $P(\mu)\subseteq P(\kappa)$. Hence there is an explicit well-ordering of $P(R(\alpha))$ via $f^{-1}_{\alpha}[ \ ]$ and the well-order $\sqsubset$ on $P(\kappa)$. Let $\lhd_{\beta}$ be this well-order. Then clearly for any $\mu<\beta$ we have $\lhd_{\beta}\cap (R(\mu)\times R(\mu))=\emptyset$.

Suppose $\beta$ is limit. Since for any $\alpha<\mu<\beta$ we have $\lhd_{\mu}\cap R(\alpha)^2\subseteq \lhd_{\alpha}$, it follows that if we put $\lhd_{\beta}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}\lhd_{\alpha}$, $\lhd_{\beta}$ is a well-order on $R(\beta)=\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}R(\alpha)$, and also for any $\mu<\beta$, $\lhd_{\beta}\cap R(\mu)^2\subseteq \lhd_{\mu}.$

Hence by transfinite induction we obtained an explicit well-order $\lhd_{\gamma}$ of $R(\gamma)$. Hence $R(\gamma)$ is well-orderable for all ordinals $\gamma$, and therefore $\mathsf{AC}$ holds.

Comment: you define $R(\gamma)$ to be the class of sets of rank $\gamma$ and you seem to be using this fact in the successor-step of your induction. In the limit-step however you're taking $R(\beta)$ to be the class of sets with rank less than $\beta$. I think your proof should still work after some minor adaptations though...

Comment: PS: you should maybe also make it a bit clearer that you are referring to Asaf's answer, not the question.

Comment: Is the last sentence of your third last paragraph a typo?  Should it be $\lhd_{\beta}\cap (R(\mu)\times R(\mu))= \lhd_\mu$? And this is because $\lhd_{\beta}\cap (R(\alpha)\times R(\alpha))= \lhd_\alpha$, and for $\mu < \alpha$ it holds by the induction hypothesis?

Comment: Actually, can you please explain a little bit more on $\lhd_{\beta}\cap (R(\mu)\times R(\mu))= \lhd_\mu$?

Answer (score 9):

No, we can’t. It’s a result due to Herman Rubin in $1960$ that if $2^{\aleph}$ is well-orderable for every well-ordered cardinal $\aleph$, then the axiom of choice holds.

Comment: It was Herman Rubin, I believe it was in 1963 or so.

Comment: @Asaf: I just checked: $\text{Rubin}^2$ came out in $1963$, but Felgner says that the result is actually from $1960$.

Comment: The result first appeared in H. Rubin. *Two propositions equivalent to the axiom of choice only under both the axioms of extensionality and regularity*, Notices A.M.S., **7**, 381 (Abstract). This is mentioned in **Equivalents of the axiom of choice, II**, in page 98.

Answer (score 1):

No. The stronger proposition already doesn't hold for $\omega={\aleph_0}$; it's consistent in absence of axiom of choice that $2^{\aleph_0}$, or the cardinality of the continuum, cannot be well-ordered.

Comment: The problem is that you need choice to show $|\mathbb{R}| = |2^\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: @goblin: No, you don't. Cantor–Bernstein is choice free.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, ah, you're right. Yet somehow I have lodged in my brain that $\mathfrak{c}$ and $\beth_1$ are fundamentally different. I wonder why?

Comment: @goblin: I don't know, I'm not your therapist! :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, no, beer is my therapist, and she's bloody good at it too :)

Comment: In hindsight, it may have been better to write cardinality of the continuum as $2^{\aleph_0}$, because if we interpret $2^{\omega}$ as ordinal exponentiation (as opposed to cardinal exponentiation - cardinality of the set of all functions from $\omega$ to $\{0,1\}$), then the expression is equal to $\omega$.

Comment: Now changed, as above.