# Choice principles implied by antichain principle in ZF - Foundation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102538/how-to-prove-the-antichain-principle-is-equivalent-to-choice) that in ZF, the axiom of choice and the
antichain principle (every partially ordered set has a maximal antichain) are equivalent. However, in ZF-Foundation, while AC still implies the antichain (maximality) principle (which I'll call AMP), the converse is not necessarily true. This also implies that the proof that AMP => AC in ZF is not "trivial".

Are there known choice principles which are implied by AMP in ZF-Foundation, something like "AMP => BPI" for example. Or "AMP => DC", etc ...

Also, is there a choice principle weaker than AC which is known to not be implied by AMP (In ZF - Foundation)?

Comment: The argument you link shows that AMP implies every totally ordered set can be well-ordered, without using Foundation.  So without Foundation, AMP cannot imply every set can be totally ordered (which is a consequence of BPI, for instance), or else it would imply AC.

Comment: As an update: In a paper by Halpern named "On a question by Tarski and a maximal theorem of Kurepa" he proves that neither Finite = D-finite nor AC(2) follow from AMP without foundation. Thus it does not follow CC, DC or AC(fin).