# Linearly ordering the power set of a well ordered set with ZF (without AC)

Tags: logic, set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

As the title says, my question is, how one can use only ZF-theory to prove that the power set of A, whereby (A, <) is a well-ordering, can be linearly ordered?

Comment: Lexicograpohically, by first difference? Where's the snag?

Answer (score 4):

Find the earliest element in the well order of A where they differ-where it is in one and not the other.  Lexicographic order would take the one with the element first.

Comment: Not that it matters, but I thought it was usual to represent membership by a $1$ and nonmembership by a $0$, and $0$ comes before $1$.

Comment: @bof:  I was thinking of each set as a string.  If we use the alphabet, a string beginning with ab comes before one beginning with ac because the b is present.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for your reply! I hve thought of this, as it was suggested in this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90078/totally-ordering-the-power-set-of-a-well-ordered-set but I don't know how to explain that it only uses ZF-theory?

Comment: Once you have a well order on $A$ (you really just need a total order) you just start down the list.  Is the first element in only one subset?  If so, that one comes first.  Otherwise, keep going.  ZF can answer is $x \in X$.

Comment: You don't "just need a total order", you need a well-order. How would you order the power set of $\mathbb R$? Which comes first, $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$? I don't believe you can prove in ZF that there is a total order on the power set of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @bof:  yes, you are right we need a well order.